# header Element prevent execution of Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

sorry for my English...

I to try an image zoom as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3cebzudv/2/) to say, it working (the image zoom) without `<header>` Tag.

[image: image without header tag]

Width the `<header>` tag

[image: show image]

When getting with the Maus on the image, the image disappears.

[image: image disappears]

Here I can show how to build my Html code.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.img').css({
    transform: 'scale(2.5)'
  });
});

$('.wrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.img').css({
    transform: 'scale(1.0)',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center'
  });
});

$('.wrapper').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.img').css({
    backgroundPosition: (e.pageX * -1) + 'px ' + (e.pageY * -1) + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="log">
    <img id="logo" src="/kalamulur/Photo/my-logo5.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="linken">
    <ul class="linken_ul">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/Kalamulur/home.php" class="dropdown"><i>Home</i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Taschen & Rucksäcke</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="tachen_rucksacke_&_Computertaschen.php"><i>Taschen, Tablettaschen & Computertaschen</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Rucksäcke</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Beutel</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Gürteltasche, Mäppchen & Schnupftabakdose</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Haus</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>Dekoration</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Teppich</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Yogamatten & Necessaire</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Kleidung</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>T-Shirts für Frauen & Männer</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Hösen für Frauen & Männer</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Schals, Mützen & Hute</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Sandalen</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Schmuck</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#"><i>Ringe, Ohrringe, Ketten ...</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Über uns</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>Über uns</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Kundenservice</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">&#127757; English</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="">Spanisch</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg');"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

I too tried **with** and **without** `<header>` Element, and to show which only working without `<header>` Element....

Can please someone help me and say where is my mistake? , Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem in the question itself.

Comment: @Andreas someone does it for me, very thanks to er/she!, next time prove not to forget this...

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, fine, if you had give your wrapper bigger size you would have seen your img does not lose it self but moves up behind header.

Problem  was  here in your js:  `backgroundPosition: (e.pageX * -1) + 'px ' + (e.pageY * -1) + 'px'`
This positioned your zoomed image behind header. If you remove it shows in box and zooms but does not update zoom on mouse movement.
I tired to play around with this but I couldn't make it work and I don't have any time for this anymore. So i am leaving this answer here maybe someone else has an idea.

I tried to play around with this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX
I could make mouse to react only for inside wrapper but I couldn't make the picture work to react to this.

Good luck.

```js
$('.wrapper').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.img').css({
    transform: 'scale(1.5)'
  });
});

$('.wrapper').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.img').css({
    transform: 'scale(1.0)',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center'
  });
});


$('.wrapper').on('mousemove', function(updateDisplay) {
var box = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var pageX = document.getElementById("x");
var pageY = document.getElementById("y");
function updateDisplay(event) {
    $('.img').css({
 backgroundPosition: (event.pageX * -1) + 'px ' + (event.pageY * -1) + 'px'
  });
}
box.addEventListener("mousemove", updateDisplay, false);
box.addEventListener("mouseenter", updateDisplay, false);
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", updateDisplay, false);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.img {
     margin-right: auto; /* 1 */
  margin-left:  auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="log">
    <img id="logo" src="/kalamulur/Photo/my-logo5.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="linken">
    <ul class="linken_ul">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/Kalamulur/home.php" class="dropdown"><i>Home</i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Taschen & Rucksäcke</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="tachen_rucksacke_&_Computertaschen.php"><i>Taschen, Tablettaschen & Computertaschen</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Rucksäcke</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Beutel</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Gürteltasche, Mäppchen & Schnupftabakdose</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Haus</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>Dekoration</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Teppich</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Yogamatten & Necessaire</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Kleidung</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>T-Shirts für Frauen & Männer</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Hösen für Frauen & Männer</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Schals, Mützen & Hute</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Sandalen</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Schmuck</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#"><i>Ringe, Ohrringe, Ketten ...</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn"><i>Über uns</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href=""><i>Über uns</i></a>
          <a href=""><i>Kundenservice</i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">&#127757; English</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="">Spanisch</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
  <span id="x"></span>
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg');"></div>
<span id="y"></span>    
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: very Thanks for your bother!, I hope someone help with the solution because I haven't Idee from JS...but I don't very optimist ..

Comment: Because I to search a jQuery inner zoom function, search on StackOverflow for other possibilities...